# Page and scripts crash

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

My page loads before being downloaded scripts, it makes the page crash sometimes.

how do I leave the page (body) ready only after loading scripts?

*Scripts*

```
<!-- SCRIPTS!! -->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**This is loaded after the body is ready with .load**

```
 <!-- Drag e Drop -->
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/dragDrop.js"></script>
```

I wonder how do I load up scripts before the body starts to load

Comment: You're question makes no sense...

Comment: Neither does your grammar. XD

Comment: On Topic: Why are you importing 3 different instances of JQuery?

Comment: I use drag drop, resizable, etc..

Comment: @pandavenger - the first is jQuery, the second is jQuery UI, and the last is the migrate plugin. Three different scripts.

Comment: why you want to prevent page load until your js file loaded? and what you mean by crash?

Comment: @Chamika Sandamal crash = page freeze!

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal the page is locked while loading scripts

Answer (score 2):

I'm suggesting you to do other way around. Best way is let page to load and then load the script files.

so your content should be in following order,

```
<body>
    <!-- your page content -->.

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/dragDrop.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: but my page is locking, there is no way to put some load to load the scripts?

Comment: I agree with @Chamika Sandamal. If loading the scripts after your page is loaded is causing problems, then there might be something wrong with the code, too. Be sure to validate your HTML to ensure that everything is working properly. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @user2403131: Update the question with extract proble. then we can help you for a SOLUTION